# Method overriding in react js

Tags: reactjs, overriding

I'm new to react js and am learning it as part of OJT. Please excuse going forward if i end up using few terms incorrectly.
I'm trying to override few methods of our core module related to logging.
However, in react js overriding is only limited to React.Component classes it seems.

i looked up few posts associated with overriding the methods as per our requirement

is there a way to override normal classes in react js? does ES6 support such a scenario and if so, is it recommended to make it work like java.

Comment: Do you have example or scenario some sort?

Comment: so i'm trying to implement Logger class for my module specifically and update the basic methods for the logging levels i.e. error, warn, info, trace etc.

This is how the core module's API is created :

class Logger{}

Comment: [Composition vs Inheritance](https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html)